# Why can't i pass this array to my target class?

Tags: java

Why can't I pass my arrays?

```
    for (int a = 0;; a++) {
        System.out.print("Enter Name:");
        name[a] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Age:");
        age[a] = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        Student student = new Student(name[], age[]);
    }
```

The Error says it needs a .class after the arrays
Help

Comment: Simple typo - `Student student = new Student( name,  age);`

Comment: ^ And declare your arrays as `String[] name` instead of `String name[]`. It's infinitely more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your constructor (i.e. what it accepts) of Student class, if it accepts array

then

Student student = new Student( name,  age); // in this case this line should be after for loop

if it accepts single name and array

then

Student student = new Student( name[a],  age[a]);

Answer (score 0):

> *Why can't I pass my arrays?*

because your syntax is incorrect, this here:

```
Student student = new Student(name[], age[]);
```

is the reason, to pass an array you normally do

```
Student student = new Student(name, age);
```

if you refer to an array in the form of a parameter then you can:

declare a method

```
void doSomeTricks(String[] args) {
```

but to call/invoke the method you do

```
doSomeTricks(myArray);
```

and not

```
doSomeTricks(myArray[]);
```